# Getting a better user experience on editing data on a continuous form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need a bit of advice. I have a continuous form that displays records where the user is able to edit the data but I'm having trouble providing a good user experience. For an edit to get validated it has to go through the BeforeUpdate event but this doesn't get triggered until the user clicks on another data row or the Exit button I placed on the form. This isn't intuitive for the user so apart from putting a message in the footer telling the user what to do I'm not sure how to do this. Are there any better ways to deal with this?

Comment: Not much different then any form when they exit move on to the next record. . I mean, for some of the required fields, or say things that are not set correct, you can put some extra code or even consider calling the same routines you have in the record before update in each of the controls after update event. So say there are 2-3 controls that need some love and care and a attention? Then just add some verification code to the after update event of those 2-3 controls, and thus they can be informed what they missed or did wrong before the move away and final before update event checking occurs

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I hadn't considered AfterUpdate so I'll give that a try

Comment: yes, we talking about after update for EACH control here - you still can/will have that before update code, but you can just have some of the verifying occur "along" the way and as the user edits the controls on that row. in fact, in some cases you want to use the beofre update event of each control, since just like the whole form, such events have a cancel event, were as after update events are too late. But for each control, you could still use after update to inform them that their data entry needs some love and care So you can allow bad data, and tell them, or choose to prevent as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate the record before it is to be saved.

Thus, you may have to validate the fields in question in the AfterUpdate events of these and, if validated, save the record:

```vb
If Me.Dirty = True Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, I'm new to Access and I am not all that familiar with the Dirty event. So I think you're saying save the record if dirty (ie something changed). So maybe it's my lack of understanding but isn't the update already made by then. Is there a way of validating all the changes and then saving them in one go?

Comment: Controls are updated when you leave them., but that doesn't update the record, only sets it's `Dirty` property to _True_.